# Can I use SSH and HTTPS both for single git account?

Tags: git, github, ssh, https, gitlab

If i use `SSH` then I have to download git repository using git ssh
but if I use `HTTPS` then https is the way.

Can I download those git repo using both way for a single account?

Comment: The answer is both no and yes. More specifically, the answer depends on the server. If the server provides both methods, you may use whichever you choose. To make a choice, spell out the correct URL: a URL that begins with `https://` will choose HTTPS, and a URL that begins with `ssh://` will choose ssh.

Comment: Thanks. Do [github.com](https://github.com) support both parallelly ??

Comment: @Shezan Yes. You can push using one or the other, but GitHub will answer to both protocols.

Comment: But github kept asking for username & password for https, even after setting up for ssh.

Comment: Do I have to setup for both https and ssh individually? How can i do that?

Comment: You don't *have to* set up both. I use ssh exclusively myself. The protocol you'll *use*, when you have your Git software contact GitHub's Git software, depends on whether you type in the URL as `https://github.com/...` or as `ssh://git@github.com/...`. (If you use `git@github.com:user/repo.git` that's equivalent to `ssh://git@github.com/user/repo.git`, but that's not a general URL rule, it's a Git-specific thing.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The account is what the remote hosting service will use to authenticate you and determine if you have the right to access the remote repository you want to clone.

- for HTTPS, it will be the username/password
- for SSH, it will be the public key published to your remote account profile setting (while the actual remote user for an SSH session is almost always a technical account like 'git': `git@remoteServer:Me/MyRepository`)

If the remote hosting service supports both protocols, the same user account can clone using either one of them.

---

If you are using HTTPS, make sure:

- to create a [PAT (Personal Access Token)](https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/keeping-your-account-and-data-secure/creating-a-personal-access-token) that you will use as password
- to check or set a credential helper (to cache those credentials)

That is:

```
git config --global credential.helper
```

I recommend setting it to `manager-core`, using the [Microsoft Git Credential Manager (GCM)](https://github.com/GitCredentialManager/git-credential-manager) (cross-platform).
It is already packaged/set with [Git For Windows](https://github.com/git-for-windows/git/releases) for instance.

Comment: @Shezan Do you still have a password issue with HTTPS?

Comment: yes. Github repo's ssh link works fine but when I try to clone repo using https it kept asking for username & password  [ and github says "Support for password authentication was removed on August 13, 2021. Please use a personal access token instead."]

Comment: @Shezan OK. I have edited the answer to address your comment.